# how to hide jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog message cursor when the message is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I use    jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog, and in the message area, I normally set it as empty    setMessage("", IMessageProvider.NONE); and message will only be assigned when there's an error occurred, like    setMessage(DialogMessages.MSG_ERROR, IMessageProvider.INFORMATION);

My question is, whenever the message is set to "", the user can see the mouse cursor on the UI when they use the TAB button to move the mouse cursor around, or they can click the empty text field directly, but they are not able to type anything there.

I don't want to show the mouse cursor at all, can anyone tell me how to modify it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to achieve this. The TitleAreaDialog does not allow enough flexibility for you access or change that message control in the title.

But if you hate this a LOT you can have access to the message control's parent and do a `Composite#setTabList(Control[])` with a list of its children that does not include this `Text` control. You can get the message control's parent by overriding `createContents` and the control returned is the parent of that message Text. That will stop tabbing to it.

But if someone clicks on it you have an issue. To solve that have a look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/371289/). This will give you a good hints to get rid of that problem.